# Return string value in Action to put it in Src of img tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, image

This is my part of View:

```
<img src="@{Html.RenderAction("GetUserProfileImage", "Home", new { area = "" });}" alt="" />
```

And My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetUserProfileImage() {

        string defaultresult = "http://MyProject.dev/Content/img/sample_user.png";
        if (Member.LogIn()) {

            DBFile file = GetMemberPicFromDB();
            return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);

        } else {
            return Content(defaultresult);
        }
    }
```

So when I Get File from DB every thing is OK, but when I return URL(by `return Content`) there is some bad result in rendered html, something like this:

```
<imghttp: myproject.dev="" content="" img="" sample_user.png="" src="" alt="">

    <div>
        some content from outside of img tag added here
    </div>
</imghttp:>
```

Also I change the View to:

```
<img src="http://myproject.dev/Content/img/sample_user.png" alt="" />
```

And every thing is OK,

So where is the problem? it seems return Content can not return simple string to `src` attribute, So what is your suggestion for return simple string?

if that not possible

I think to get File by URL(`http://myproject.dev/Content/img/sample_user.png`) and `return File()` Like when returned from DB, but how can I get the file in controller by this URl(`http://myproject.dev/Content/img/sample_user.png`) ?

and any other suggestion if you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a file from your controller action in both cases and reference this action in your image, like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetUserProfileImage", "Home", new { area = "" })" alt="" />
```

and then in your controller action return a File result in both cases:

```
public ActionResult GetUserProfileImage() 
{
    if (Member.LogIn()) 
    {
        DBFile file = GetMemberPicFromDB();
        return File(file.Content, file.ContentType);
    }
    else 
    {
        string image = Server.MapPath("~/content/img/sample_user.png");
        return File(image, "image/png");
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be work, but I don't know where is the problem, I check the `image` content that exactly is the path of the file in the server but with this return all of the html of the page Bombed!!, have you any idea about this?